# Optimizing searches for big MySQL table

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm working with a MariaDB (MySQL) table which mainly contains information about the whole world cities, their latitude/longitude and the country code (2 characters) where the city is. The table is so big, over 2.5 milion rows.

```
show columns from Cities;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| city    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lat     | float        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lon     | float        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to implement a city searcher, so I have to optimize the `SELECTS`, not the `INSERTS` or `UPDATES` (it will be always the same information).

I thought that I should:

1. **create an index** (by city? by city and country?)
2. **create partitions** (by country?)

Should I do both tasks? If so... How could I do them? Could anyone give me several advices? I'm a little bit lost.

PS. I tryied this to create and index by city and country (I don't know if I am doing it well...):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cities ON Cities(city (30), country (2));
```

Comment: You should always index columns where you perform a search on.

Comment: OK, that's understood. How should I do partitions on this table (if needed)?

Comment: Show us the queries.  _They_ are the clue to what index(es) to have.

Comment: Index cookbook:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* use "prefix indexing".  Simply use `INDEX(city, country)`  This will work very well for either of these:

```
WHERE city = 'London'   -- 26 results, half in the US
WHERE city = 'London' AND country = 'CA'  -- one result
```

Do *not* use Partitions.  The table is too small, and there is no performance benefit.

Since there are only 2.5M rows, use `id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` to save 2.5MB.

What other queries will you have?  If you need to "find the 10 nearest cities to a given lat/lng", then see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql).

Your table, including index(es), might be only 300MB.

Comment: You meant don't use `city (30), country (2)` , isn't it?

Comment: @Ommadawn - `city(30)` saves a little space, and is the only way to index a `TEXT` (although only partially).  It prevents going on to subsequent columns (eg, `country`) in a composite index.